# Create Histogram with bellcurbe with in the same chart Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with highcharts 9.0.1 and Im trying to use histogram-bellcurve.js to create an histogram with a bellcurve but I cant get it.

This is what I'm traying.

```
                          // Bell Curve Chart
                    Highcharts.chart('container', {

                        title: {
                            text: 'Bell curve'
                        },

                        xAxis: [{
                            title: {
                                text: 'Data'
                            },
                            alignTicks: false
                        }, {
                            title: {
                                text: 'histogram'
                            },
                            alignTicks: false,
                            opposite: true
                        },{
                            title: {
                                text: 'Bell curve'
                            },
                            alignTicks: false,
                            opposite: true
                        }],

                        yAxis: [{
                            title: { text: 'Data' }
                        }, {
                            title: { text: 'Bell curve' },
                            opposite: true
                        }],

                        series: [{
                            name: 'Bell curve',
                            type: 'bellcurve',
                            xAxis: 1,
                            yAxis: 1,
                            baseSeries: 1,
                            zIndex: -1
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Histogram',
                            type: 'histogram',
                            xAxis: 1,
                            yAxis: 1,
                            baseSeries: 2,
                            zIndex: -1
                        },     {
                        name: 'Data',
                        type: 'scatter',
                        visible:false,
                        data: data,
                        accessibility: {
                            exposeAsGroupOnly: true
                        },
                        marker: {
                            radius: 1.5
                        }
                    }]
               });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lvevano/g9czr63s/6/

Is there a way to create this kind of chart ?

[image]
greetings!

Comment: I am not sure what do you have in mind - you actually created a histogram chart and hide those series. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yq2atjr6/ Could you explain where the problem is?

Comment: The idea is to create both series (histogram, bellcurve ) in just one chart. I pasted an example of what I'd like it to looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a very basic example, based on what you posted. You can play with the properites to make it look better, but this should do what you asked.

```
series: [{
      name: 'Bell curve',
      type: 'bellcurve',
      data: data,



    },
    {
      name: 'Data',
      type: 'histogram',
      data: data

    }
  ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u1s0d2pa/1/

Comment: Thanks... it worked well. Just modify some parameters and now its working. 
Fiddle Updated https://jsfiddle.net/lvevano/xcjayvtw/178/